# Check if image exist in a big loop

Tags: php

I'm doing a check like this:

```
// ADDITIONAL PRODUCT IMAGE
$add1 = @get_headers("https://{image_server_link}/DIx.jpg_RB2000,2000,255,255,255,127/-/article/" . $product_number . "_1.jpg");
if(strpos($add1[0], "404") === FALSE) {
    // Image found, so let's print it out
}
```

It's inside a CSV generator, and because of the csv contains 2000+ products the `get_headers` slows down generation from 3 to 4 MB/S to 10-15KB/s. As our CSV is 6.9 MB this will take ages.

Is their any other option to check if an additional image exists which is faster?

---

*By the way, the images are hosted on a seperate image-server with varnish caching, so it's not possible to do a `is_file` function or something..*

Comment: You'd be better off using a stream wrapper (or using curl) and turning on keep-alives. If you're doing a get_header() call for 2000 images, that's 2000 full-blown http connections to establish/use/teardown. A keep-alive will reduce that to a single tcp connection, which gets used multiple times. And better yet, if that's YOUR image server, you should have access to the raw file system and could put in a script that lists available files. "Here's what I have" is going to be FAR more efficient than "do you have X" "do you have Y" "do you have Z" etc...

Comment: You could look into doing the requests in a non-blocking manner. The CSV file would be read but the requests would take a while to do after that (Perhaps doing them in parallel is a good idea?)

Comment: I think it would be better suited to hide the image if it does not load client side, the amount of server side processing would be time consuming unless it is a one time thing you run once in awhwile.

Comment: It's for Google Shopping, works with headers for a csv file so images are not shown @DavidNguyen. Thanks Marc B for the tip. As it's my image server I do have a list of available images, but how to combine it with the CSV? Passing an array of 12.000 image names doesn't sound good to me... Do I need to store the image names in a DB and do a check over MySQLi like I do with the other data?

Comment: if strpos returns 0 (which means position 1) it will match `== false`. Use `=== false`

Comment: Thanks @DanFromGermany, true, fast mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a php script on the other side that gives you a list of available images or checks for availability of multiple images at once (a web service).

Edit:

Or just use the index page of the image directory.